# Класс как поле класса

Tags: c++, ооп

Как хранить объекты классов в качестве полей другого класса? к примеру, :

```
class A
{
    A(int s)
    {

    }
};
class B
{
    B(double s)
    {

    }
};
class Res
{
    A one;
    B two;
    Res(int w, double d)
    {
        this->one = new A(w);
        this->two = new B(d);
    }
};
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

В вашем случае вот так:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int s){}
};

class B
{
public:
    B(double s){}
};

class Res
{
    A one;
    B two;

public:
    Res(int w, double d)
    : one(w)
    , two(d)
    {}
};
```

---

**Пояснение:**

1. Ваши конструкторы классов `A` и `B` (да и `Res` судя по всему тоже) должны находиться в `public` области (модификатор доступа у `class` по умолчанию `private`, в отличие от `struct`, у которого, как раз, `public`), т.к. иначе вы не сумеете создать экземпляр данного класса из вне (т.е. за пределами методов данного класса), за исключением случаев использования `friend` функции/класса и замыканий
2. Инициализация полей класса посредством `direct initialization`

Comment: Спасибо, такой вариант сработал

Comment: Создать экземпляр можно используя `friend` функцию/класс.

Comment: @alexolut Не думаю, что автору вопроса стоит это знать сейчас, а то может начать программировать в таком стиле там, где это неуместно.

Comment: Вопрос, как и ответ, видят не только ТС и Вы, поэтому информация по возможности должна быть наиболее полной.

Comment: @alexolut Убедили, подправил :) Будем надеяться, что этим не станут злоупотреблять читатели.